# How does one obtain the lavfi.aphasemeter.phase frame metadata in FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg, phase

I'm trying to derive the numeric representation of a sound file's phase.

FFMPEG's aphasemeter filter seems to fit the bill for computing this number; the docs explicitly say:

> The filter also exports the frame metadata lavfi.aphasemeter.phase which represents mean phase of current audio frame. Value is in range [-1, 1]. The -1 means left and right channels are completely out of phase and 1 means channels are in phase.

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#aphasemeter

However, I can't seem to figure out how to use this filter to get that numeric value. When I experiment with various commands, I get various error messages. For example, `ffmpeg -i input_file.wav -f aphasemeter.phase` says I need an output, but `ffmpeg -i input_file.wav -f aphasemeter.phase output_file.txt` produces `is not a suitable output format \ output_file.txt: Invalid argument`

I'm looking for that -1 through 1 value; a graphical representation of that--though seemingly the main point of that filter--is not what I'm looking for.

Any ideas?

In case it matters, I'm using the WSL, having installed ffmpeg by apt-get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logged metadata values can be accessed and exported using the (a)metadata filter.

```
ffmpeg -i in.wav -af aphasemeter=video=0,ametadata=print:file=inwav-phase.txt -f null -
```

The text file will have the data in the format,

```
...
frame:105  pts:107512  pts_time:2.23983
lavfi.aphasemeter.phase=0.600750
frame:106  pts:108536  pts_time:2.26117
lavfi.aphasemeter.phase=0.554201
...
```

Comment: One comment to add to this excellent answer is that on Windows, path information in the text file part of the command (...ametadata=print:file=c:\fake\path\inwav-phase.txt for example) will cause problems. *nix systems are ok with that, however.

Comment: You have to escape and quote the path: `file='c\:\\fake\\path\\inwav-phase.txt'`